need to prove that $DSPACE(O(2^n)) \neq EXP$
this question is from my computational complexity HW.
I'm not sure if my solution is correct:
If $DSPACE(O(2^n)) = EXP$, than we can take language $ L \in DTIME(2^{2^n})$ which not in $EXP$ (from the time hirarchy we have a language like that).
Choose $f(n)=2^n=m$ for padding, so the padded language $L_{pad}^f \in DTIME(2^n) \subset EXP$. We obtain that $L_{pad}^f \in DSPACE(O(2^n))$, and we have a TM that solves $L_{pad}^f$ in $c2^n, c\in R.$
Now we will show a TM that solves $L$ in exp time: for an input $x$ of length $n$, we will pad $x \to y=x!1^{2^n-n-1}$ (! is just a special char to know where the padding starts). than we can use the TM mentiond above and decide $x \in L \iff y \in L_{pad}^f \iff TM(y)$
accepts. From the initial assumption we obtain $DTIME(2^{2^n})=EXP$ and that is a contradiction.
I think there is something wrong with the solution, because we can get from it that $DTIME(2^{2^n}) \subseteq DSPACE(O(2^n))$, and clearly $DSPACE(O(2^n)) \subseteq DTIME(2^{2^n})$ (the configuration graph), so we get $DSPACE(O(2^n)) = DTIME(2^{2^n})$ and i'm pretty sure that this is unknown.
To sum up, if you know what is my mistake and what is the right solution to the question, i'll be greatful.

I agree that such an $L$ exists by THT and that $L_{pad}\in \text{DTIME}(2^n),$ but from there I'm not really grasping your argument. Where is $L_{pad}\in \text{DSPACE}(O(2^n))$ (or anything about space, per se) used?
The reasoning then seems to be that we can decide $L$ in exp-time by padding, and then passing to a $\text{DTIME}(2^n)$ decider for $L_{pad}$, but that doesn't work. When we pad $x$ with $2^{|x|},$ $y$ has length $2^{|x|},$ so the $L_{pad}$ decider decides $y$ in $2^{|y|}= 2^{2^{|x|}}$ time, so this isn't exponential time in $|x|.$
I may have missed something, but anyway, here's an approach to solve it. For  these kinds of exercises, the trick is usually to show one side is closed under some kind of reductions and the other isn't.
By space-hierarchy there is an $L\in \text{DSPACE}(2^{n^2})\setminus\text{DSPACE}(O(2^n)).$ Let $L_{pad}$ be $L,$ padded with $n^2-n-1.$ Then we can see using similar padding arguments to what you initially used that $L_{pad}\in \text{DSPACE}(O(2^n))$ And also note, just by computing the pad and tacking it on, that $L$ polynomial-time reduces to $L_{pad}.$
Thus, $\text{DSPACE}(O(2^n))$ is not closed under polynomial time reductions. But $\text{EXP}$ is, so they are not the same class.

First, thank's. Your solution is great and I learned from it.
I truly have a mistake in my solution. @spaceisdarkgreen
